# Angular2 disable left navigation component for a particular screen

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-routing

I have an angular2 app where I have one Header component,one left nav component and the main body content which changes based on routing.The left navigation gets enabled based on the routing.For example- when I am on first screen, the first screen text gets highlighted in left nav.When I reach the last screen, the entire left nav is enabled as I have been through all the pages.I want the left nav component to be disabled for the last screen.
In my case, my last screen is confirmation. i am trying to do something like this-

In my services-

```
isConfirmation :boolean = false;
```

In my confirmation.ts-

```
ngOnInit(){
this.services.isConfirmation = true;
}
```

The flag is being set as true.

In my leftNavigation.html-

```
<nav>
   <md-list [disabled]="services.isconfirmation">
        //left nav items
    </md-list>
</nav>
Using [disabled]="services.isConfirmation" throws syntax error.
```

I tried putting the [disabled] attribute for nav tag but I am still seeing the syntax error.

The left nav is getting displayed properly but its not getting disabled for the confirmation screen.I am hoping if that's because of using md-list.Not very sure with the usage of md-list but that's the way the list is being populated.Using [disabled]="services.isConfirmation" throws syntax error.

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this: Using [disabled]="services.isConfirmation" throws syntax error.  Please post this error in your question.

Comment: @chrispy updated.

Comment: maybe your services doesn't exist yet. Try this : `services?.isConfirmation`

Comment: @mickdev services exist.I am using that service throughout my app.

Comment: @techiequestie I meant to post the syntax error itself.